# Closure activates on load, not checkbox change

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to attach an onchange event to a checkbox created by js.

I finally gotten the closure to work inside a for loop, but now it activates on load rather than on change.

Why is this?

https://jsfiddle.net/dkrh587h/2/

```
  chkbox.addEventListener("change", (function(newVarA, newVarB, newVarC, newVarD) {
    searchMap(newVarA, newVarB, newVarC, newVarD);
  }(gblStatus, "Status", statuser, chkbox.checked)), false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are invoking the function being passed as the second argument to `addEventListener` with the extra parenthesis.

This is sometimes called a [self-executing](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) function:

```
function() {
    // will get invoked immediately
}();
```

Variables like `statuser` will be available in your callback because of closure (assuming they are declared within a function-scope that "encloses" your posted code).

A pattern like this should work:

```
var statuser = 'my user'; // will be available in your callback
chkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
  searchMap(gblStatus, "Status", statuser, chkbox.checked);
}, false);
```

Comment: That was my first problem.  Whenever I tried that, I only got the last element in the for loop.

Comment: @Emwat I see. That's a classic case of confusion with closures. I would recommend using `gblStatus.forEach` instead to avoid that problem. See this answer for information why that problem happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example